# If $\lim_{x\to x_0} (f (x) − g (x)) = L$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0} f (x) = L+\lim_{x\to x_0} g (x)$ .

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f,g$ , be two different functions defined on a deleted neighbourhood of ${x_0}$ and let $L ∈ \Bbb R$. Prove or disprove each of the following claims:

If $\lim_{x\to x_0} (f (x) − g (x))  = L$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0} f (x) = L+\lim_{x\to x_0} g (x)$.

I think i just have to give a counter example because you can easily can see its not true.. i don't find a good counterexample

Comment: No straight solution to this question will help to your understanding. First you need to look at your notes and find a relevant theorem saying almost what's written in here. Then you have to check the assumptions of this theorem and try to find a function which does not satisfy one of the assumptions that will be a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does not exist and let $g=f$. For instance, you could take $x_0=0$ and
$$
f(x)=g(x)=\sin\frac1x.
$$

Comment: thank you julian. i can't suppose that g = f ** they have to be different

Comment: Well, take $g(x)=f(x)+\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\phi(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Take both to be $1/x$ and $x_0=0$. The difference is zero, so is its limes, but on the other hand $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{1}{x}$$ is not defined in an epsilon interval around 0.